# infopath connecting to an access database on Sharepoint

Tags: database, ms-access, sharepoint, infopath

I have an Access Database (accdb) with relationships (and linked tables) that is incompatible with Access Services. It is currently saved locally but I have it on a SharePoint site as well.

I also have created an Infopath form that queries the local Access Database for different fields, and is able to submit data back to make changes to the tables, etc.

I now want to shift the connection to the database that is saved on the SharePoint site. I went to modify my Main data connection (the locally saved Access Database), changed database to point it to the access database that is on the SharePoint site. It definitely recognized that it was an Access Database, because it even showed me my tables and queries and asked me to select a table. But when I do so, it says there is "An unspecified error occurred while attempting to
connect to the data source. Microsoft Office InfoPath supports only MS SQL
Server and MS Office Access databases. Please check the connection to ensure
it uses one of these two databases."

Would any of you know how to resolve this error, without having to set up SharePoint Lists to connect back to my Access Database (I don't see how this would allow the initial querying of the data that my InfoPath form has to do).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database it Access 2013 or older, older versions of access aren't supported in SharePoint to modify.

I would create with Access 2016 a database that lives in the SharePoint Data Connected Library and connect to that.